# Do error terms of a value that is part of a normal distribution also follow a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, normal-distribution, error, function

I asked this yesterday, but was not very concise.  Hoping to get better results with different wording.  I have a question related to the error term in a normal distribution.  Let's assume that we are taking IQs at various high schools.  we go to one high school, take 5 IQ's and the mean is 140.  we go to another, take 5 IQS and the mean is 60.  We are trying to determine the population mean at each school.  Of course, We know that the 140 and 60 are just estimates of the respective high schools,  is there some "boundedness" concept (seems intuitive) that would suggest that the real mean at the one school is more likely higher than 60 than lower, and the mean at the other school is more likely lower than 140 than higher.  I am thinking of a probability density function of error terms about each of 60 and 140 would illustrate that.  Can we confirm this mathematically?   Thanks  John

Comment: I can't really connect your text to the title. The question text (after the "related" sentence) doesn't involve the normal distribution at all.

Comment: I suspect that in order to achieve what you have in mind, this somehow would need to be incorporated in some way as a model assumption. For example, you could go Bayesian and assume that the true and unobserved school-wise means are generated from a prior distribution that puts high probability around 100 and becomes lower at both sides. Such a model will implicitly enforce that if you observe extreme means such as 60 or 140, you should expect the true means a bit closer to the assumed overall mean of 100.